# Cube Mapping vs Spherical Mapping

Tags: cubemap, sphere

I am currently researching the difference between Cube Mapping and Spherical Mapping.

Wikipedia [says the following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_mapping):

> In the majority of cases, cube mapping is preferred over the older method of sphere mapping because it eliminates many of the problems that are inherent in sphere mapping such as image distortion, viewpoint dependency, and computational inefficiency. Also, cube mapping provides a much larger capacity to support real-time rendering of reflections relative to sphere mapping because the combination of inefficiency and **viewpoint dependency** severely limits the ability of sphere mapping to be applied when there is a consistently changing viewpoint.

How are cube maps NOT viewpoint dependent?

And does this imply that pretty much in every case Spherical Maps can be replaced by Cube Maps? Or are there exceptions? (some examples would be nice)

Comment: Is there a specific application where you're considering to use a sphere map vs a cube map?

Comment: @DMGregory hi, no not yet. I was just doing some research on the differences betwen the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding reflections:

Cube-maps are capturing the whole reflection space around the pivot on the cube, regardless of the camera's facing direction. Whereas spherical maps capture only the space that is facing the camera (and hence the map needs to be re-drawn for each viewing direction)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The edit made it easier to understand